# Why "mount | grep sdb" displays no output, when "sdb" drive is a [swap] partition?

Tags: mount, grep, storage, regex, mass-storage

I'm learning about `lsblk` and `mount` commands in Ubuntu.
I'm using Linode vps server, 2CPU, 4GB ram with 1 additional block storage volume attached.

I have 2 questions related with this subject.

At first I've run `lsblk` command:

```
michal@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda    8:0    0 79.5G  0 disk /
sdb    8:16   0  512M  0 disk [SWAP]
sdc    8:32   0   50G  0 disk /mnt/movies
```

Here I understand everything.

`sda` and `sdb` are both the default partitions I had, when I first created my linode and `sdc` is the block storage volume I've attached later.

Then I've run `mount` command with `grep`, like this:

```
michal@ubuntu:~$ mount | grep sda
/dev/sda on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
michal@ubuntu:~$ mount | grep sdb
michal@ubuntu:~$ mount | grep sdc
/dev/sdc on /mnt/movies type ext4 (rw,relatime)
michal@ubuntu:~$
```

1. Why `mount | grep sdb` returns no output?? This is my `[SWAP]` partition.

Then I've run:

```
michal@ubuntu:~$ mount | grep sd?
michal@ubuntu:~$
michal@ubuntu:~$
```

2. Why `mount | grep sd?` returns no output??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`swap` is not a filesystem, it's not mounted, it's activated or deactivated (see `man swapon`). A mountpoint does not exist. In `/etc/fstab` the mountpoint is specified as `none`. Since `swap` is not mounted, I'd not expect the swap partition to appear in the output of `mount` or `findmnt`.

`mount | grep sdb` gives no output because the string `sdb` does not appear in the `mount`-output. Remember, `/dev/sdb` is your swap, it is not mounted.

`mount | grep sd?` gives no output because the string `sd?` does not appear in your `mount`-output. A drive named `sd?` does not exist, as simple as that. If you want `grep` to treat `sd?` as an extended regex, you'd use `mount | grep -E sd?` and your output wouldn't be empty but it probably wouldn't be what you expect since the meaning of the `?` is very different in regex and globbing.

`mount | grep "/dev/sd"` is what gives you the output you desire here.

---

Some more details:

From `info grep` chapter 2.4 'grep' programms:

```
’-G’
‘--basic-regexp’
     Interpret patterns as basic regular expressions (BREs).  This is
     the default.
```

From `info grep` chapter 3.6 Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions:

```
Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
       In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose
       their special meaning; instead use  the  backslashed  versions
       \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).

    Portable scripts should avoid the following constructs, as POSIX says
    they produce undefined results:
    
    ...
    • Basic regular expressions that use ‘\?’, ‘\+’, or ‘\|’.
    ...
```

But even when I use `\?` it does not work as expected for me, `mount | grep sd\?` still gives empty output which definitely shouldn't be the case. It only gives me expected output with the `-E`-option, with or without the backslash. Probably this is a bug.

Comment: on a side note `mount | grep /dev/sd?` will give an error, as it expand to `mount | grep /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc`

Comment: `grep` uses regular expressions by default, you do not have to specify the `-e` parameter. As the manpage for `grep` says, the `-e` parameter is "used to specify multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with a hyphen". Otherwise it is not needed.